# show the value of the graph when cursor is placed on the graph

Tags: java, visualization, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart to draw the graphs. I need to show the value when the cursor is placed on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ToolTipManager. If you can register the graph as a component, you can assign a specific tooltip to it which will be displayed automatically.

If you cant use the default version it's also possible to write a custom ToolTipManager, which displays the tooltip when the cursor is over certain areas on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used jfreechart tooltips before, but that maybe what you're looking for.

There a series of chart specific tooltip interface/classes in the org.jfreechart.labels package. For example, using a XyToolTipGenerator with an [XYItemRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYItemRenderer.html#setBaseToolTipGenerator(org.jfree.chart.labels.XYToolTipGenerator)) may do what your looking for.